# How TestFlight is helpful for us

Tags: iphone, ios, ipa, testflight

My client wants I use TestFlight for sending files. But I am new in TestFlight I read as much as possible in TestFlight and also stack over flow questions about TestFlight. Anyone tell me features of TestFlight. How it is useful for me and also for client? and it is possible to make build .ipa file without developer certificate with the help of TestFlight ( I know i deserve down vote for that ), but i have to short time to find the answer of that.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

TestFlight makes it easier for you to distribute your app to your beta testers and collect feedback from them. You can also use their SDK in your app to put markers in to see whether certain parts of your code or application was used.

It doesn't let you build apps without a certificate. You need to build an Ad-hoc distribution, and your beta testers will need to sign up with a TestFlight account and their devices will have to be registered with your developer account.

Comment: + 1, furthermore TF SDK installs a crash report. When an app crash happens, you can see the log...

Comment: is it possible for the client to take the code that is uploaded to test flight? client wants to test the ios build i am working on in TF before sending final payment.

Comment: Nope. They only get the ipa with the ad-hoc certificate. They don't get the code. They cant compile it with the app store cert and deploy it themselves.